# Time travel movie with a spinning time machine

Tags: identify-this-movie, time-travel

I've been looking for a long time for the name of a (probably) made-for-TV movie involving a time travel machine that spun like a small carousel, with a teenage boy and girl sitting on it. After having gone back in time, the boy and girl visit a middle-aged man's suburban house (possibly the inventor). As far as I can remember, all the characters were human.

It was an American, English language movie. That's all I can remember about it. I saw it on TV about 15 years ago. It was possibly made in the early 90s.

It's not 'The Blue Yonder' (1985).

Comment: Can you give some more information about the time machine itself? Did the machine look like something? Was the machine itself spinning or...?

Comment: Did the children grow up to marry? Were there two characters in suits, one red and one yellow, who turned out to be the children grown up?

Comment: was there a boy in a crow like mask on the cover cause i think we are thinking of the same movie? but i cant find the name of it. there was also a bunch of kids living in an opera house. im also pretty sure the word thief was in the title.

Answer (score 3):

Is it Something Wicked This Way Comes? I remember a demonic aging carousel in that, although it's a little older than what you described.

Comment: Sadly it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Also possibly too old (1988) and British rather than American, but it does sound suspiciously like [Moondial](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098866/)

Comment: No, it wasn't a children's fantasy-type TV series. I'm sure it was a movie, and as far as I can remember, all the characters were human.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the movie you could be looking for is The Theif Lord. I watched this movie many years ago as a kid and could never remember enough information about it to find it. Lia's comment gave me the last piece of the puzzle. I kept searching things like The Raven Prince because all I could remember was the mask he wore and that his title was some kind of nobility and about the aging carousel. I hope this is what you are looking for. http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0430674/

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it. Been seeing your comment for a few years because I was looking for the same film. I finally found it. Running Against Time 1990 is the film. About a man who goes back to save his brother in Vietnam by stopping JFK from being killed. The video clip on IMBD looks like the right film.

Hope you are still checking this thread and see this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Does this film have a teenage boy and girl in it like the one I remember?